# A software like Proxifier for linux?

Tags: linux, proxy, socks-proxy

is there any software similar to Proxifier in windows for linux that passes all of my traffic via SOCKSv4, SOCKSv5, HTTPS and etc.?

Comment: **[FULL DETAILED ANSWER](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/516047/120919) PROXIFIER LIKE FOR LINUX**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes you can use [proxychain](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/)

**About proxychains tool:**

```
 * It's a proxifier.
 * Latest version: 3.1
 * Dedicated OS: Linux and other Unices.
 * Allows TCP and DNS tunneling through proxies.
 * Supports HTTP, SOCKS4 and SOCKS5 proxy servers.
 * Different proxy types can be mixed in the same chain.
 * Proxy chain: user-defined list of proxies chained together.
```

**Usability :**

```
 * Run any program through proxy server.
 * Access the Internet from behind a restrictive firewall.
 * Hide your IP
 * Run SSH, telnet, wget, ftp, apt, vnc, nmap through proxy servers.
 * Access Intranets (192.168.*.*/10.*.*.*) from outside through reverse proxy.
```

Comment: A somewhat newer version is called proxychains-ng: https://sourceforge.net/projects/proxychains-ng/

Comment: Also https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Proxy/Proxybound as alternative ;)

Comment: Procychains is NOT a Proxifier-like software, it only allows to start a single program with it if you are able to start the part of it that does network work over command line. Proxifier applies to all instances of configured programs (you don't have to do `proxifier program.exe`). In addition to that, proxychains does not work with Java. I wish there was a real linux alternative for it..